# How do create a file from ascii, then create a link to download the file with Laravel

Tags: laravel, ascii

I'm using a shipping api, that has a method that spits out a pdf in this format (ascii, I believe):

```
 %PDF-1.3\n1 0 obj\n
    <<\n
    /Type /Pages\n
    /Count 1\n
many lines removed here
    startxref\n
    982\n
    %%EOF\n
```

How do I..

1. Convert this code into a downloadable .pdf file?
2. Create a link to download the file?

Note - I do not need to store the file.

ADDENDUM

So, this is moving the correct file to the correct place, but is giving me an error "Call to a member function move() on string".

```
$pdf_raw = $this->create_label2($data->label_url);
$filename = 'label'.auth()->user()->id.'.pdf';
file_put_contents($filename, $pdf_raw);
        
$filename->move(public_path().'/img/pdf', $filename);
```

How can that be?

Comment: @KJ - Thank you - please see edit / addendum.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    $pdf_raw = $this->create_label2($data->label_url);  //this is raw ascii data
    $filename = 'label'.auth()->user()->id.'.pdf';  //can be any name .pdf
    Storage::disk('pdf')->put($filename,$pdf_raw);  //creates file and moves to correct path
            
            
    $pdf_link = "/mypath/$filename"; //url to file
```